# WinCVS Macro assign keyboard shorcut

Tags: python, tcl, cvs, cvsnt, wincvs

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to my most used command - Macro->TCL->Revert Changes. I have found how to assign [shortcut to python scripts here](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/cvsgui/message/14703) but not to TCL.

Alternatively, I can try to create a python script with assign shortcut and then call the TCL script, but since I don't know neither Python or TCL, I don't know whether this is possible or how long it would take me

Help greatly appreciated